# OpenLiteSpeed vs Apache real mySQL benchmark

Tags: apache

I have read so many good things regarding the performance of OpenLiteSpeed and I ran a sample for loop of 1 million inserts on mySQL.

I did the same on my current Apache installation. My current Apache ended the task in 183 seconds, where the OpenLiteSpeed throwed an error page after some minutes. However in that 4-5 minutes did not even reach the half of the inserts.

I used the digitalocean's configuration for the OpenLiteSpeed.

Both servers have 1 CPU.

Am I missing something here? I was expecting OpenLiteSpeed to win hands down.

Thank you

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
From SSH login, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: It seems like testing mysql performance but web server. You can also install both web servers on the same server with port offset. Like above suggestions, more environment information would helps.